# Skype for 8.1 login fails - "Oops, please check your details."

Tags: login, windows-8.1, skype

I can log into skype just fine from several different devices including Windows 7 and Android.  I can see my account details on the skype website.  But attempting to log in to the Windows 8.1 version always yields "Oops, please check your details."

Has anyone ever successfully logged into skype from windows 8.1?  How do you do it?  The error message is rather gratingly friendly but un-helpful.

Comment: I am currently logged into both the Windows Store Skype application and the Skype Desktop application on all my Windows 8.1 machines.  I should point out I am able to use either my Skype account or the linked Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is silly, but for the benefit of anyone else struggling with this, you need to use your skype account name, not your email address for this login.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 is both a tablet (Store Apps) and a PC (.exe programs).
I've soved this issue by unstalling the "tablet app" (right click, then click uninstall) then installing Skipe.exe from Microsoft.
Hope it helps.